# Disabling Toggle Button Throws External Exception

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

```
private async void AddVoice_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AddVoice.IsEnabled = false;

    await Task.Delay(100);

    AddVoice.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

This is a simpler snippet than my actual code, but I found these three lines are where the problem is.

It always throws at the second line: await Task.Delay(100). The exception is external code and I'm not sure how to catch it.

I found that if I disable the button in a non-async method (constructor for example), it doesn't throw. Disabling it in other async methods will throw.

I'm able to modify other controls' properties in this method.

Comment: What exception? That might help if you tell us. Also, are you using ConfigureAwait on your async calls?

Comment: So what's the exception? Can you post it?

Comment: @ToniPetrina In the call stack it just says UnhandledException [external code]